# ORA-01830: Limit the data depends on specific time variation

Tags: sql, oracle

I just need to show the ORD_DT after applied in 4 months.

e.g. if the APP_DT is 2018/01/01, it would show 4 rows, which the ORD_DTs are 2018/01/01, 2018/02/01, 2018/03/01, and 2018/04/01.

I tried the query below, but I got the wrong message "ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string".

Could anyone help? Thanks.

```
select a.id, a.app_mon
, to_date(ORD_DT, 'YYYY-MM') as ORD_DT
, add_months(to_date(ORD_DT, 'YYYY-MM'),3) as IN_3_MONTHS
from CN_NEW_APPLICANT
where a.id = 'CN00300323' 
and h.dist_id = a.id
and to_date(ORD_DT, 'YYYY-MM') < to_date(add_months(a.app_mon,3),'YYYY/MM/DD');
```

The data for your reference:

```
+------------+------------+------------+-------------+
|     ID     |   APP_DT   |   ORD_DT   | IN_3_MONTHS |
+------------+------------+------------+-------------+
| CN00300323 | 2018/01/01 | 2018/01/01 | 2018/04/01  |
| CN00300323 | 2018/01/01 | 2018/02/01 | 2018/04/01  |
| CN00300323 | 2018/01/01 | 2018/03/01 | 2018/04/01  |
| CN00300323 | 2018/01/01 | 2018/04/01 | 2018/04/01  |
| CN00300323 | 2018/01/01 | 2018/05/01 | 2018/04/01  |
| CN00300323 | 2018/01/01 | 2018/06/01 | 2018/04/01  |
| CN00300323 | 2018/01/01 | 2018/07/01 | 2018/04/01  |
| CN00300323 | 2018/01/01 | 2018/08/01 | 2018/04/01  |
| CN00300323 | 2018/01/01 | 2018/09/01 | 2018/04/01  |
| CN00300323 | 2018/01/01 | 2018/10/01 | 2018/04/01  |
| CN00300323 | 2018/01/01 | 2018/11/01 | 2018/04/01  |
| CN00300323 | 2018/01/01 | 2018/12/01 | 2018/04/01  |
+------------+------------+------------+-------------+
```

Note:
APP_DT means the start date of the month that one customer joined, and it's date format.
ORD_DT is the month that one customer purchased, and its format is string (YYYY-MM). But I showed the data as a date format above.

Comment: please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did the error showed some line number so as to which line the error was pointed to

Comment: Why are you storing DATE values in VARCHAR columns - that is a really bad idea

Comment: Your reference data has nothing to do with the columns in your data.  Where is `APP_DATE`?  What is `COMM_YYYY_MM`?

Comment: I edited some info so that you can refer to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`to_date(add_months(a.app_mon,3),'YYYY/MM/DD');` statement is wrong

you first need to convert to date then you need to use add_months

```
add_months(to_date(a.app_mon,'YYYY/MM/DD'),3);
```

PS: I am not sure about your logic, which is why I didn't comment.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the column type of `a.app_mon` but you have at least one implicit type conversion in this statement `to_date(add_months(a.app_mon,3),'YYYY/MM/DD');`.

If it's of type `date` you just need `add_months(a.app_mon,3)`. The additional `to_date()` causes the result of `add_months()` (which is of type `date` already) implicitly converted to `varchar2`, which most likely doesn't match the given format string.

If it's of type `varchar2` you first need to convert it to a `date`: `add_months(to_date(a.app_mon, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 3)`. Make sure that the format string matches the actual text.
In this case there's a second implicit conversion from `varchar2` to `date`, since `add_months()` requires a first parameter of type `date`.

**Edit:**

Another reason for this error may be that the values in the column `ORD_DT` contain texts that do not match the format "YYYY-MM".

Comment: I tried both, but it failed... The strange thing is that if I changed the "<" to "=", it would be fine... Plus, the a.app_mon format is `date`.

Comment: Could it relate to the date format in the setting? I changed the format to "YYYY/MM/DD"

Comment: @Chris: Channing `<`to `=`will result in less rows being selected and therefore having the `to_date(h.COMM_YYYY_MM, 'YYYY-MM')` in the select clause being performed less.

Comment: Yes, I know. Unless I can make sure that every date can be stored or changed the start date of the month... But I have no idea why there's the error...

Comment: Have you checked to content of column 'ORD_DT`? It must not contain strings other than YYYY-MM. Is it of type VARCHAR2?